# Why is "eines" genitive in "eines frühen Abends"?

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun, genitive

This is a line from *"Der Vorleser"* by Bernhard Schlink:

> Eines frühen Abends im Februar hörte ich eine Amsel singen.
>
> One early evening in February I heard a blackbird singing.

**eines (masc+genitive+singular)**

**frühen (masc+genetive+singular)**

**Abends(m) (genitive+singular)**

Why is the *eines* in the genitive?  "One" is not belonging to anything.

Why isn't it like this:

> einer frühen Abends

This is a sentence from one of my textbooks:

> einer meiner Handschuhe fehlt
>
> one of my gloves is missing

The "einer" in this sentence in masculine and nominative.

--- EDIT ---

Thanks for the help.  I was confusing the pronoun "einer" meaning "one of" with the article "ein" meaning "a" or "one".

[image: Graph of: one early morning in October]

Comment: Please, be more careful, unless you don't care about careless answers. Begin with the book title; it is _Der Vorleser_.

Comment: _"einer frühen Abends"_ is totally wrong. Should be _eines frühen Abends_.

Comment: In “einer meiner Handschuhe”, “einer” just means “one”, The “of” is expressed by the genitive in “meiner Handschuhe”.